# What is the purpose of Archaeologist badge?

Tags: discussion, edits, badges

There's a few questions/answers on Archaeologist badge but none of them really answered what's I'm interested in: what's the purpose of this badge? In other words, what behaviour or action is it meant to promote?

Old questions will be bumped up to the top of the list if I edit them but is it going to do much good? Is it meant to promote editing old questions that I feel should be still looked at and answered? But then, why should I be forced to do it by editing them?

I feel it may be too easy to just edit old posts (especially if I have 2k+ rep) without much gain for the website and its users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of the badge is to encourage cleaning up old questions; the attention they might receive because of the edit is not the primary goal.

Cleaning up could include fixing broken links, adjust posts for changed formatting, adding in now-available popular tags, etc. However, the exact criteria for the badge are most likely kept vague on purpose, to avoid gaming.

Like any archaeologist, you will probably have to work through a lot of dirt and fairly useless broken pottery before you find the silver!

Answer (score 1):

You are not forced to edit them. Only slightly encouraged.

Questions and answers here are supposed to be a knowledge repository. But world changes, IT world faster than others. Keeping good old questions updated is worth a reward.

You shouldn't change a meaning of old question, but keeping API links updated and providing current names for libraries that got renamed are perfectly valid and needed edits.

Comment: But I you can't update questions by editing them. Editing is not meant to change the meaning of a post, just formatting, grammar, etc.

Comment: @Szymon But sometimes names of libraries change. Or API links. That you can and should update.